# Ramifications of using a stored procedure as a returned object as opposed to using a foreach to populate a data model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here are two examples of methods, the first one uses a foreach statement to populate a data model

```
public List<TheOrderSummary> GetTheOrderSummaryByID(int id)
    {
        ExoEntities = new ExoEntities();
        List<TheOrderSummary> lst = new List<TheOrderSummary>();

        foreach(var a in query)
        {
            lst.Add(new TheOrderSummary
            {

                OrderDetailID = a.OrderDetailID,
                OrderHeaderID = a.OrderHeaderID,
                ItemSeq = a.ItemSeq,
                MaterialID = a.MaterialID,
                Description = a.Description,
                DWidth = a.DWidth,
                DLength = a.DLength,
                MaterialArea = a.MaterialArea.ToString(),
                MaterialDetail = a.MaterialDetail,
                DHeight = a.DHeight,
                PurchUnitOfMeasure = a.PurchUnitOfMeasure,
                SellUnitOfMeasure = a.SellUnitOfMeasure,
                MaterialCategory = a.MaterialCategory,
                MaterialType = a.MaterialType,
                MaterialSubType = a.MaterialSubType,
                ColorID = (int)a.ColorID,
                Color = a.Color,
                MaterialPrice = a.MaterialPrice,
                MaterialCost = a.MaterialCost,
                MaterialLocationID = (int)a.MaterialLocationID,
                MaterialLocation = a.MaterialLocation,
                LaborPrice = a.LaborPrice,
                LaborCost = a.LaborCost,
                VendorID = (int)a.VendorID,
                VendorName = a.VendorName,
                Size = a.Size,
                Height = (decimal)a.Height,
                Length = (decimal)a.Length,
                Width = (decimal)a.Width,
                PurchaseQuantity = (decimal)a.PurchaseQuantity,
                SellQuantity = (decimal)a.SellQuantity,
                TotalFootage = (decimal)a.TotalFootage,
                GeneratedItemInd = (int)a.GeneratedItemInd,
                ExtendedMaterialPrice = (decimal)a.ExtendedMaterialPrice,
                ExtendedLaborCost = (decimal)a.ExtendedLaborCost,
                ExtendedMaterialCost = (decimal)a.ExtendedMaterialCost
            });
        }

        return lst;
    }
```

and this one uses a stored procedure to return an object

```
public List<usp_GetTheOrderDetails_Result> GetTheOrderSummaryByID(int id)
    {
        ExoEntities = new ExoEntities();

        var query = ExoEntities.usp_GetTheOrderDetails(id);

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Both of these are in a DAL and the method that could call either one of these is a JSONResult, both of these can be used to populate a grid. What ramifications would using the second type be down the road as opposed to the first one? They both return the exact same thing, from the looks of it on a performance level, without doing the numbers, the second one would be faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pain that is introduced by returning the result directly is that you get a "hard-wired" dependency on the information contract between the consumer and the underlying data provider. If you make a change to the underlying data structure, you must update the client at the same time (which may come with various degrees of pain).

If you instead go with your first option, you encapsulate the knowledge of the underlying information structure into this layer, and may use that to map between the old and new contracts, thereby decoupling the direct dependency between the client and the data provider.

So yes, the second option might bit a tad faster (even though that really should be marginal), but the first one is likely to give you much less pain when it comes to maintaining code and deployments in the longer run.

Comment: Excellent explanation, so sometimes less code isn't always the best thing, in this case anyways